# Where to keep user's id?

Tags: java, web, profile

I am designing a web application which should keep the user's profile that has lots of information, 
obviously it reads the data from database.

Currently, I have the username in my session and everytime I need the user's info should read the session then create an object of profile class (that read the data from database again) to retrieve user's info, is it the best practice for such an issue?

Comment: i updated my answer based on your comments

Answer (score 1):

Generally a 'best practice' is to maintain the User profile data in session and load all needed information only the first time from the database.

In other words mantain an instance of `Profile`class in your http session (must implement `Serializable`). Profile must hold all the informations used *more frequently*.

Note that 'reading the session' is like reading an HashMap (so has a minimum cost in term of performances).
When the `HttpSession` will expire, Profile will be garbage collected.

UPDATE (based on your comments) :

to count (or find) active users (inactive are all the others), a typical solution is make `Profile` implements the `HttpSessionBindingListener` interface. When `Profile` is bound to a session, is notified, so you can increment a static counter (a static attribute of Profile class for example),and you can decrement it when the `Profile` is unbound (programmatically unbound or because its session has expired)

Comment: Yes I am using java so how to find if user is logged in do you have any sample code?

Comment: when the user log in, you will put a Profile class in session, when he logout you will invalidate the http session (httpSession.invalidate()), than depend from your technology (servlet, jsf, ecc). Take a look at JEE Tutorial...

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical trade-of between performance and memory consumption. If you want a fast application, keep the whole user profile in HTTP session but make sure you have enough memory in your server.

If you want to keep resource consumption low, store only user ID in session and load it from a database every time you need it. This also makes clustering simpler as there is less data to migrate.

Reasonable compromise is to use the latter approach with some caching. This way *hot* users (currently using the system) are kept in memory, while idle users or infrequently accessing new pages are swept out from cache (assuming cache is smaller then the number of HTTP sessions).

Comment: @EmeEmertana: if you use virtually any caching library, it'll handle this for you. Basically when you have 101 items and you want to put them in cache that has capacity of 100, caching library will remove the oldest/least recently used/... one

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Obe6 response, 
Best practice is to ensure if the profile is not in session then to retreive from a datasource and then attach it to a session.

When session is invalidated then all information is removed from session. 
There is a good article on this from IBM. 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/bestpractices/store_objects_in_httpsession.html

Answer (score 0):

Session is generally a good enough place to keep the user profile data.  You need to quantify how much of data you are talking here. Let's say its 5KB per session, then, you could store up to 20000 user profile in memory using 100 MB of RAM. You can allocate heap to JVM accordingly based on the max. number of active sessions you expect on your site.

This is just one aspect. When you plan to scale the app by adding more app servers, then, you can even think of moving the sessions out to a out-of-process cache/memory stores such as memcached.

If all the user profile data you keep in session does not get rendered on each page, then, it may be a good idea only to keep bare minimum in session and fetch other data as per need.

Comment: Shreenvias, How to find the inactive users?

Comment: All sessions are always active, even if user is inactive.  Sessions typically expire on their own after a period of user inactivity.  So, it is good idea to assume that most user will not logout explicitly, and their session will be around in memory for some time.  If we assume session timeout is 30 min, then plan to support as many sessions as much users you expect to be active in half hour window.